# Can a number see fluctuations?

Tags: sentence-construction

I read in a [post](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/modest-increase.299343/) about the use of "saw".

[image]

According to that post, a number can't see fluctuations. The use of "saw" in the sentence below must be wrong?

> 1. The **number** of shops that opened in this country **saw** large
>    **fluctuations.**

It has to be:

> 2. This country saw large fluctuations in the number of shops that
>    opened.

However, someone who answered [another question of mine](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/321352/is-it-correct-to-use-the-singular-number-with-both) says "The shops did not see fluctuations. The number did."  That is to say, he thinks that a number can see fluctuations. My question is whether Sentence 1 is correct or not.

Comment: You are arguing that bringing a story to life by pretending that numbers see is not factual. True. But it makes for a good story, so it's common.

Comment: I'm not arguing. I'm just not sure if what I read in another forum is correct or not. Sorry, I don't understand you. What is common?

Comment: "Arguing" here means putting a position forward, not disagreeing. "Common" means it is very ordinary to see phrasing like "numbers saw" because it brings the words to life. If engineers are literal and dislike the looseness of this wording, they can do so. But they should expect their attitude to **see** many instances anyway.

Comment: This person isn't an engineer, they're an English teacher—and never trust an English teacher who boldly proclaims that something is wrong. I'm studying engineering and we use this all over the place.

Comment: There are plenty of hits for +"numbers have seen an increase" in google. The "seen" here is not literal.  We know the numbers can't literally see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that "jutfrank" wisely says "These are not right, *in my view*." I don't think you can expect an authoritative ruling that either of these usages is universally *wrong*; you have found a difference of opinion. But I don't know that you can hold [the older SE question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/321352/138287) as an example to the opposite of this screenshot. The sentence there,

> The number of shops that opened and the number that closed both saw wide fluctuations during the entire period.

... isn't the same as these. The subjects of that sentence are two statistical data points—they *are* numbers—and there isn't really another easy way to refer to them. In jutfrank's examples, there is both a statistic and a context for the statistic (gorillas in Cameroon, sales at Apple). The "shops opened/closed" statistics presumably belong to some similar context, and perhaps jutfrank would prefer recasting the sentence along those lines:

> Brooklyn saw wide fluctuations in both the number of shops opened and the number that closed.

But it also seems reasonable to me, if the context is so well established that it doesn't need to be stated, to make the fluctuating data point itself a subject.